# WebView shows white screen on Samsung S4 android 4.2.2 for AT&T in onResume()

Tags: android, webview

This is the code to my WebView. It works great on every device I have tested so far, even a Samsung S4. However, a certain Samsung S4, which the client insists it doesn't have a modified software, displays a white screen every time the app is resumed from background. Any ideas?

```
private void setupWebView() {

    // hide the no connection imageview
    // show the webview

    noConnectionImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
             handler.proceed();

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            showNoConnectionImage();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            // page has started loading
            if (mustShowSplashScreen) {
                showSplashScreen();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            // page has finished loading

            if (mustShowSplashScreen) {
                hideSplashScreen();
                mustShowSplashScreen = false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            // check for Internet connection
            if (ConnectionDetector.isConnected(Main.this)) {
                // check if link is external
                if (isExternalUrl(url) {
                    // external link
                    new OpenLink(Main.this, url);
                } else {
                    // internal link
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }
            } else {
                showNoConnectionImage();
                Main.this.url = url;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: can you please share your css

Comment: unfortunately, no. I do not have acces to that.

Comment: I have the same problem on Samsung Note 3.